# Spring Security OAuth2 disable BasicAuthenticationFilter from default filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In Authorization Server, need to add custom BasicAuthenticationFilter due to some manipulation of client id. Mostly implementation is same as `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. Following is snippet of same,

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    ...
    ...
    String username = someDecoder(tokens[0]); // Kind of something
    ...
    ...
}
```

And my custom filter placed before `BasicAuthenticationFilter` in filter chain.

```
http.addFilterBefore(new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), authenticationEntryPoint()),
    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

This custom filter working as awesome and user also get authenticated successfully. But due to BasicAuthenticationFilter still present in chain, this filter is also get executed and try to authenticate user again but fails because of not manipulated client credentials. See [BasicAuthenticationFilter-GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L174)

So to remove/disable `BasicAuthenticationFilter` from filter chain followed this [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237715/how-to-delete-one-filter-from-default-filter-stack-in-spring-security), where suggested to use `BeanPostProcessor`. But in Spring Boot filter chain registered with bean name **springSecurityFilterChain** and class **`FilterChainProxy`**. As [FilterChainProxy-GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a82cab7afdb1fc58830b1c415f1874d36b2c6c92/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L249) returning unmodifiable list of `SecurityFilterChain`. So its next impossible to alter `FilterChainProxy` bean.

So how to achieve same or any other way to remove/disable `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or any other filter from Spring Security Filter chain.

Using Spring Boot 1.5.1 and Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.12

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428154/2648577

---- >>> this is a copy/paste (changing filter name).

> By default Spring Boot creates a `FilterRegistrationBean` for every
>   `Filter` in the application context for which a
>   `FilterRegistrationBean` doesn't already exist. This allows you to
>   take control of the registration process, including disabling
>   registration, by declaring your own `FilterRegistrationBean` for the
>   `Filter`. For your `BasicAuthenticationFilter` the required
>   configuration would look like this:
>
> ```java
> @Bean
> public FilterRegistrationBean registration(BasicAuthenticationFilter filter) {
>   FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
>   registration.setEnabled(false);
>   return registration;
> }
> ```
>
> You may also be interested in [this Spring Boot
>   issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2173)
>   which discusses how to disable the automatic registration of `Filter`
>   and `Servlet` beans.

Comment: From [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-listener-as-spring-bean). You can only disabled those filter/servlet which are registered with `FilterRegistrationBean`. Where as `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is not registered with same. [Check](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a82cab7afdb1fc58830b1c415f1874d36b2c6c92/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HttpBasicConfigurer.java#L208)

Comment: Specific error of trying your solution is this `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter' in your configuration.`